# pgBackRest not compatible with EDB Advanced Server 12

Tags: docker, edb, pgbackrest

PostgreSQL : EDB Advanced Server 12.15.19
pgBackRest 2.43
OS: RHEL 9

Build a binary using rhel9 but getting below issue

`pg_basebackup: error: incompatible server version 12.15.19 pg_basebackup: removing data directory "/data/enterprisedb/12"`

Can someone please help me out with the above error .